# Unable load a url from a database

Tags: mysql, ios, url, uiwebview, xcode5

This code allows me to pull image names from my mysql lite database without any issues.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad

{

    [super viewDidLoad];

    UIImage * image = [UIImage imageNamed: self.munsterData.image];

    self.imageView.image = image;

}
```

I would also like to pull specific urls from my database and load them into a UIWebView using this code:

```
    - (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    NSURL * myUrl = [[NSURL alloc] initWithString: self.munsterData.twitter];

    NSURLRequest * myNSURLRequest = [[NSURLRequest alloc]initWithURL:myUrl];

    [twitterView loadRequest:myNSURLRequest];

}
```

What am I doing wrong? My app instantly crashes when I select the url link. If I replace:

`NSURL * myUrl = [[NSURL alloc] initWithString: self.munsterData.twitter];`

with

`NSURL * myUrl = [[NSURL alloc] initWithString: @"http://www.google.com"];`

The google website loads successfully. But for some reason I cannot get url's from my database to load.

munsterData:

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableArray * munsterData;
```

twitter:

```
const char * twitterStr = sqlite3_column_text(statement, 7);
NSString * twitter = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:twitterStr];
p.twitter = twitter;
```

Comment: What does the crash log say? Is self.munsterData.twitter a string object?

Comment: Perhaps you can show us what the `self.munsterData.twitter` string value is.

Comment: I have included string info as requested.

Answer (score 0):

Put this right after the [super viewDidLoad]; and provide feedback.

```
NSLog(@"%@", self.munsterData.twitter);
if ([self.munsterData.twitter isKindOfClass:[NSString class]]) {
    NSLog(@"is string");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You Code is perfect for loading any url in UIWebview. good way to start. But make sure the below points before loading url in UIWebview with the example of your code:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
   [super viewDidLoad];
   NSURL * myUrl = [[NSURL alloc] initWithString: self.munsterData.twitter];
   NSURLRequest * myNSURLRequest = [[NSURLRequest alloc]initWithURL:myUrl];
   [twitterView loadRequest:myNSURLRequest];
}
```

1. Debug your code and check if "self.munsterData.twitter" is getting url or not. Good way to program is to check if your string has value or not only than after than perform another operation on string.
2. Check if you string Contains "http://" or "https://"  in your "self.munsterData.twitter". if not available than please add using string with format method of NSString Class.
3. For Better Programming, Please use the method for converting in to real url with the below method:

   ```
   - NSString *url_String = [self.munsterData.twitter  strgingByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
   ```